# What's the facebook rate limit for an application with 0 connected users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Reading this documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

I have seen that the limit of calls per hour depends on the number of users connected to the application (200 multiplied by the number of users). I would like to know what the limit is in the case of an application with 0 users that only obtains data from public pages.

Another question: if we connect users, what is the call limit to obtain that type of data if we use the application's token, instead of the user's token?

Comment: _“I would like to know what the limit is in the case of an application with 0 users that only obtains data from public pages.”_ - well zero times 200 would still be zero, at least in theory … but you probably at least have an app admin user, and even if they don’t log in daily, then the alternative method of calculating the limits should apply. _“what is the call limit to obtain that type of data if we use the application's token, instead of the user's token?”_ - quote: _“Application-Level Rate Limiting: These limits apply to calls made using any access token other than a page access token.”_

Comment: It is not 0 because our app is currently alive and manages to obtain data, but it often exceeds the limit of allowed requests. I think that are 200 but I'm not sure. These limits are strange because Facebook allows you to create applications by requesting the only permission: Page Public Content Access